# Beautifulsoup functionality not working properly in specific scenario

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, html5lib

I am trying to read in the following url using urllib2:  http://frcwest.com/ and then search the data for the meta redirect.

It reads the following data in:

```
   <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title></title><meta content="0;url= Home.html" http-equiv="refresh"/></head><body></body></html>
```

Reading it into Beautifulsoup works fine. However for some reason none of the functionality works for this specific senarious, and I don't understand why. Beautifulsoup has worked great for me in all other scenarios. However, when simply trying:

```
    soup.findAll('meta')
```

produces no results.

My eventual goal is to run:

```
    soup.find("meta",attrs={"http-equiv":"refresh"})
```

But if:

```
    soup.findAll('meta')
```

isn't even working then I'm stuck. Any incite into this mystery would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What version of Beautifulsoup are you using? Using `import requests; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup; BeautifulSoup(requests.get(your_url)).find_all('meta')` works fine for me..

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for the quick response. I am using bs4. However to import, parse the data i am using httplib2 and html5lib. Based on both your response and Martijn's response, it looks like that is the source of the error. It appears that you are using the requests library ( from python-requests.org ) to make it work. I didn't know about that resource, I will play with it further, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the comment and doctype that throws the parser here, and subsequently, BeautifulSoup.

Even the HTML tag seems 'gone':

```
>>> soup.find('html') is None
True
```

Yet it is there in the `.contents` iterable still. You can find things again with:

```
for elem in soup:
    if getattr(elem, 'name', None) == u'html':
        soup = elem
        break

soup.find_all('meta')
```

Demo:

```
>>> for elem in soup:
...     if getattr(elem, 'name', None) == u'html':
...         soup = elem
...         break
... 
>>> soup.find_all('meta')
[<meta content="0;url= Home.html" http-equiv="refresh"/>]
```

Comment: Thanks for the great incite and comment, mystery solved! Been banging my head against this issue for a couple days, thanks for the clear and prompt response.