# BeautifulSoup4 not recognizing xml tag

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup4 (with lxml parser) to parse xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<data>
<metadata id="8735180"  name="Dauphin Island" lat="30.2500" lon="-88.0750"/>
<observations>
<wl t="2013-12-14 00:00"  v="0.725" s="0.059" f="0,0,0,0" q="v" />
<wl t="2013-12-14 00:06"  v="0.771" s="0.066" f="0,0,0,0" q="v" />
<wl t="2013-12-14 00:12"  v="0.764" s="0.085" f="0,0,0,0" q="v" />
```

....etc

The python code is like so:

```
obs_soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?product=water_level&application=NOS.COOPS.TAC.WL&begin_date=20131214&end_date=20131216&datum=MSL&station=8735180&time_zone=GMT&units=english&interval=&format=xml),'lxml')

for l in obs_soup.findall('wl'):
    obs.append(l['v'])
```

I keep getting the error:

```
for l in obs_soup.findall('wl'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134384/beautifulsoup-functionality-not-working-properly-in-specific-senario) (except instead of looking for 'html', I looked for 'data'), but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code, as posted, doesn't even get far enough to produce that error, because there's a `SyntaxError` from the line that constructs `obs_soup`, from a missing quote. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) rather than just code that's vaguely similar to your actual code; it makes it much easier to debug things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

---

First, there is no such method as `findall` in `BeautifulSoup`. Change that to:

```
for l in obs_soup.find_all('wl'):
    obs.append(l['v'])
```

… and it will work.

---

So, why are you getting this `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` instead of the more usual `AttributeError`? Because of BeautifulSoup's magic lookup—the same thing that lets you do `obs_soup.wl` as a shortcut for finding a `<wl>` also lets you do `obs_soup.findall` as a shortcut for finding a `<findall>`. Because there is no `<findall>` node, it returns `None`. And then you're trying to call that `None` object as a function, which of course is nonsense.

---

Also, if you actually had copied and pasted the copy from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134384/beautifulsoup-functionality-not-working-properly-in-specific-senario) as you claimed, you wouldn't have had this problem. That code uses `findAll`, with a capital "A", which is a deprecated synonym for `find_all`. (You shouldn't use the deprecated synonyms, of course.)

---

Second, you're explicitly asking for lxml's HTML parser instead of its XML parser. Don't do that. See [the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser):

```
BeautifulSoup(markup, ["lxml", "xml"])
```

Since you didn't give us a complete XML document, I don't know whether this will affect you, or whether you'll happen to get lucky. But you shouldn't rely on happening to get lucky when it's so easy to actually do things right.

Comment: Thank you! That's ask very helpful, and I'm sure that typing findAll or find_all will fix it.

Comment: @RyanSchuster Then you should upvote this answer and accept it. Don't be rude.. :)

Comment: Sorry 'bout that. I *did* find parts of this answer to be rude. "But you shouldn't rely on happening to get lucky when it's so easy to actually do things right." --> Could have left that out since I just made a simple mistake...a bit condescending if you ask me. "Also, if you actually had copied and pasted the copy from here as you claimed" --> Never claimed that I copy/pasted (which I clearly didn't). I don't like the implication that I'm making things up. "Since you didn't give us a complete XML document" --> NOAA wouldn't let me link to the XML, so I copy/pasted enough to make the point.

Comment: @RyanSchuster: Posting code that doesn't actually run, and fragments of examples instead of complete stripped-down examples, and claiming that you "tried the solution here" when you've clearly introduced a mistake that was not in the solution you tried are all ways of wasting the time of people who are trying to help you, and future searchers who may find your question. If you're too thin-skinned to deal with that being pointed out to you, people aren't going to want to help you.